# Build tensorflow: name 'json' is not defined

Tags: tensorflow, bazel

When building `tensorflow` from sources with `bazel` I have got error:

```
io_bazel_rules_go/go/private/sdk.bzl:337:12: name 'json' is not defined
```

How to add the dependency or import `json` library?

The code looks like python source, so I have tried to `import json`, which does not work.

1. clone tensorflow repo:
   `git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow.git`
2. configure

```
PYTHON_VERSION=python3.10
PYTHON_BIN_PATH=$(which $PYTHON_VERSION) \
PYTHON_LIB_PATH=$($PYTHON_VERSION -c "import pip; print(pip.__path__[0].rstrip('/pip'))") \
TF_NEED_CUDA=0 \
TF_NEED_ROCM=0 \
TF_DOWNLOAD_CLANG=0 \
CC_OPT_FLAGS="-march=native -Wno-sign-compare -mnoavx" \
TF_SET_ANDROID_WORKSPACE=0 \
TF_ENABLE_XLA=1 \
TF_NEED_OPENCL_SYCL=0 \
TF_NEED_MPI=0 \
./configure
```

3. and build
   `bazel build`

My environment:

```
Ubuntu 22.04 LTS (all installed packages are up-to-date)
bazel 3.5.1- (@non-git)
tensorflow branch r2.11
```

Comment: You are solving the wrong problem, you probably have a version of bazel that is too old

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I have added info about my env.

Comment: I have Bazel 5.3.2, your is too old (I already said this).

Comment: Yes! My bazel was too old. Now I have installed (downloaded) 5.3.2 and this is worlking. Thank you Dr.Snoopy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated above, 3.5 is too old.

```
sudo dpkg -P bazel-bootstrap

sudo npm install -g @bazel/bazelisk
```